# Mathjax updated rendering of Latex equations

Tags: typescript, mathjax

I have been using this code to render Latex. However, when I update my equation the rendered HTML doesn't refresh. I tried finding documentation for `typeset()` and `typesetPromise()` but could not find much to help with the code example here:

```js
//rederMath.tsx 
import { mathjax } from 'mathjax-full/js/mathjax';
import { TeX } from 'mathjax-full/js/input/tex';
import { CHTML } from 'mathjax-full/js/output/chtml'
import { AllPackages } from 'mathjax-full/js/input/tex/AllPackages';
import { browserAdaptor } from 'mathjax-full/js/adaptors/browserAdaptor';
import { RegisterHTMLHandler } from 'mathjax-full/js/handlers/html';

RegisterHTMLHandler(browserAdaptor());

const html = mathjax.document(document, {
  InputJax: new TeX({
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    packages: AllPackages
  }),
  OutputJax: new CHTML()
});

html.findMath()
  .compile()
  .getMetrics()
  .typeset()
  .updateDocument();
```

Is there a way to get updated HTML after equation was changed?

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the [MathJax issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/issues/459) that you started, MathJax keeps track of the steps that have already been performed so that it doesn't have to redo them if the process is interrupted (for dynamic loading of an extension, for example).  But this also means that the steps won't be performed a second time unless you tell MathJax that you want them to be.  You do that via `html.reset()`.  So

```js
html.findMath()
    .compile()
    .getMetrics()
    .typeset()
    .updateDocument()
    .reset();
```

would allow you to repeat the process.

This example is an old one, and there is a newer API that does the first fix steps for you (plus any additional steps that are registered as `renderActions` such as adding the MahJax contextual menu, and so on).  It is

```js
html.render()
    .reset();
```

though you can still do the individual steps as you have done, if you wish.

If you are updating the *same* equation frequently (i.e., replacing it with a new equation), then you will probably also want to call `html.clear()` rather than `html.reset()` in order to remove the record of the previous expression (otherwise the list of typeset expressions will grow, since it included all the past versions of the expression as well).